# Finding all ordered tuples

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose $a+b+c+d+e=t$ and $a,b,c,d,e \geq r$ where all the given variables are positive integers.

How do you calculate all ordered tuple of $a,b,c,d,e$ such that the above equation holds.

The stars and bars formula can't be applied here, since we have a restriction namely $t$, for all the integers.

You can use an explicit example with any positive integers to explain these type of problems. Thanks.

Comment: Since there are two many variables ($a,b,c,d,e$) to call their choices "pairs", you might refer to such a selection as a quintuple (five ordered items), or generally the word "tuple" may be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a problem like this, just subtract the obligatory $r$ units from each of the variables $a,b,c,d,e$ to obtain new variables $a'=a-r$ etc.. Then one has five otherwise unconstrained non-negative integers $a',b',c',d',e'$ satisfying $$a'+b'+c'+d'+e'=t-5r.$$ Assuming the right hand side is non-negative, the number of solutions is $\binom{t-5r+4}4$ (among $t-5r+4$ units choose $4$ to be separations between the remaining $t-5r$ of them).

Comment: I am sorry, even $e \geq r$. Thanks, I got it now.

You can edit your answer to avoid confusion among the others in the community.

Comment: Isn't it $\cdots=t-5r$?

Comment: Yes, and that is not his fault but mine.

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer